# interaction between apps

Tags: android

Hi everyone i am doing Mphil in computer science...i came across that interoperability amoung mobile apps is difficult to achieve...........so i am going to try answer this question in my mphil dessertation.....so thought to make some ground works.....it would be a honor if u guys help me achieving it.....

1. is it possible for different apps on the same device to interact?
2. are there any existing ways to do this?if so what are they?
3. is this commonly done in industry?
4. if so what are the overheads involved?
5. has this been tried by anyone before?

Comment: sorry but why is interoperability defficult to achieve? If you lookup the Android developer page you can interact with another application via Intents.

Comment: @PoweRoy its been stated difficult because of different vendors creating them....so how does this work exactly...is it one way or a two way communication.........

Comment: It might be difficult on other platforms. On Android there're several well documented, well stablished ways of doing it. Intents, Content Providers and BroadcastReceivers comes to my mind, but it's likely that there's even more. Maybe you should re-think your dissertation subject. edit: @maximshoustin reminded me.. there's also services that you can just bind to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can by using Bound Services and Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL).
[Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Answer (score 0):

One of the method is to use [**BroadcastReceiver**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) at both ends to exchange information. It is a commonly used technique to share date between applications.

Using [**Content Providers**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) may be another option for you to consider.

As far as I know, these two are the simplest way of sharing data among apps.